# best practice in reading all sensors data

Tags: android, design-patterns, sensors, android-sensors

I'm new into android development, and at this stage I try to mimic some functionalities from other apps (please consider the image from bellow).

For example, there is one app o google play which gives details about all the sensors from a device. I know how to read the values from any sensor and how to get a list of all the sensors, but I don't know how to take all the values from all the sensors and to display them in real time.

Are there some good practices or design patterns which can help me achieve the real-time values in an elegant manner?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to design this  you have to use fragment on main activity then you have to use viewpager and tabhost to swipe tab and then you have to use recycler view or list view to display data then u have to use censer data try any one censer then u will get deep onto in censer its easy library .first you design this.

Comment: I'm not asking about the UI implementation. I just don't know how to get all the data at once.